# What are the steps to upgrade Traefik from v1 to v2 on GKE Kubernetes with ACME SSL terminator?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, traefik

How to upgrade Traefik from v1 to v2 on GKE Kubernetes?

Currently, I'm using Traefik v1 as a reverse proxy with ACME SSL terminator on my GKE Kubernetes cluster. I recently upgraded my Kubernetes cluster to version 1.23 and found that Traefik v1 no longer works properly with this new version.

I want to switch to Traefik v2 to address this issue. However, I'm unsure about the specific steps I need to follow to upgrade from Traefik v1 to Traefik v2 on my GKE Kubernetes cluster.

Could you please provide a detailed guide on how to correctly perform this upgrade process? Are there any special considerations or precautions I need to keep in mind?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have much to take care on **GKE** side however on **traefik** you have to update the **YAML** files as many breaking changes there.

In **v1** it is used to create the **frontend**, **backend** and normal **ingress** resource however with **v2** there are few **CRD** resources like **IngressRoute**, **Middleware**.

If you are fully changing from **ingress** to a **gateway** type solution you have to take care SSL/TLS part also as it's supported in different ways.

Hopefully, you will be able to use the existing secret which stores you cert.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: testtls
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure 
  tls:
    secretname: ssl-cert
```

i would recommend checkout once the official doc : https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/migration/v1-to-v2/

Comment: thanks, you are actually right. I thoroughly researched the documentation and I'm using helm to deploy to my clusterer.

Thanks for the suggestion